# Cannot properly parse and display Json

Tags: java, json

```
while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    jsonData = inputLine;
    System.out.println(jsonData);
    
}

JSONObject object = null;
try {
    object = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(jsonData);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JSONObject weather = (JSONObject) object.get("weather");
String description = weather.get("description").toString();

System.out.println(description);
        
in.close();
```

The above code produces the following error:
[image: Error]

The code I've attached starts at line 38. I want to try to print out the "description" field from the Json I have parsed.

The relevant part from the json is:

```
"weather": [ { "id": 800, "main": "Clear", "description": "clear sky", "icon": "01n" } ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Parsing a JSONArray to JsonObject
at below line in ur code

```
JSONObject weather = (JSONObject) object.get("weather");
```

**weather** is a `JsonArray`
I tried below code it worked for me.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"weather\": [ { \"id\": 800, \"main\": \"Clear\", \"description\": \"clear sky\", \"icon\": \"01n\" } ]}");
       JSONArray weatherArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
       JSONObject weatherJson = weatherArray.getJSONObject(0);
       System.out.println(weatherJson.get("description"));
    }
```

**output**

```
clear sky
```